# .NET code executing in one tab prevents other tab from loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs

My issue is regarding the behavior of a C# ASP.NET application when using multiple tabs.

What's happening is, if a user has the same system open in 2 tabs and they run a process that takes some time in one tab, the other tab is also unusable until the first has finished loading.

For example, if they are looking at reports in one and data management in another, if they run a report which takes 1 minute to load, the data management tab will also be unusable for 1 minute.

Is this normal behavior? Are there any ways around this?

Comment: Are you talking about multiple browser tabs or multiple tabs within a web page? Which browser?

Comment: I'm talking about multiple browser tabs. I have reproduced the behavior in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

Comment: No it's not normal behavior. Without knowing more it's difficult to say, but it could very well be that the process is so resource intensive the server isn't responding to other requests. IIS is designed to serve large numbers of simultaneous requests and usually takes something intensive to block. The code itself may even lock things, it's hard to know without seeing more.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick - normal or not, it is somewhat expected behavior for default ASP.Net application with SQL session state for example. Session state locks access for R/W, so if multiple slow R/W requests that are made in the same session (like in OP case - multiple tabs in the same browser) then they will run sequentially...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. I think you've nailed down the issue. The first query is pulling a LOT of data from the db and must be locking it so not data can be pulled out for the 2nd tab until the 1st is done.
No for a follow up: if I close tab 1, should it cancel execution and allow tab 2 to begin loading? It seems to complete the queries from tab 1 even after it has been closed.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Good point. I avoid session state like the plague since classic ASP days so hadn't realized that it puts a lock on sesison automatically now.